# Countdown timer in Angular pipe not working using pipe and map

Tags: javascript, angular, timer, rxjs, angular-pipe

I'm a little new to RXJS so not really sure how the Pipe and Map are being used here, but the line below never gets called. It's inside a pipe and map.

> return this.msToTime(this.getMsDiff(futureDate));

On the screen, I just see [object, object], instead of the countdown timer.

Here is the [git repo](https://gist.github.com/craigiswayne/f3ebe749c4023d345aedccc47120bf02) for this Angular pipe.

I've created a [Stacklitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-example-ezbpsb?file=app/app.component.html) that shows no output on the screen. If you uncomment out the pipe map section you will see nothing but [object, object] on the screen.

**EDIT** - If I replace the pipe and map with a subscribe like below I can see the incremental values in console.log, but nothing shows on the screen.

```js
const source = timer(0, 1000);
const abc = source.subscribe(val => {
  const timeRemaining = this.msToTime(this.getMsDiff(futureDate));
  console.log(timeRemaining);
  return timeRemaining;
});

<span class="float-right yb-color">{{event.datePendingUtc | timeRemaining}}</span>
```

```js
/**
 * @param futureDate    should be in a valid Date Time format
 *                      e.g. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.msz
 *                      e.g. 2021-10-06T17:27:10.740z
 */
public transform(futureDate: string): Observable < string > {
  /**
   * Initial check to see if time remaining is in the future
   * If not, don't bother creating an observable
   */
  if (!futureDate || this.getMsDiff(futureDate) < 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(() => {
      // never gets hit
      return this.msToTime(this.getMsDiff(futureDate));
    })
  );
}

/**
 * Gets the millisecond difference between a future date and now
 * @private
 * @param   futureDate: string
 * @returns number  milliseconds remaining
 */
private getMsDiff = (futureDate: string): number => (+(new Date(futureDate)) - Date.now());

/**
 * Converts milliseconds to the
 *
 * @private
 * @param msRemaining
 * @returns null    when no time is remaining
 *          string  in the format `HH:mm:ss`
 */
private msToTime(msRemaining: number): string | null {
  if (msRemaining < 0) {
    console.info('No Time Remaining:', msRemaining);
    return null;
  }

  let seconds: string | number = Math.floor((msRemaining / 1000) % 60),
    minutes: string | number = Math.floor((msRemaining / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours: string | number = Math.floor((msRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  /**
   * Add the relevant `0` prefix if any of the numbers are less than 10
   * i.e. 5 -> 05
   */
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  hours = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;

  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

Comment: Before returning the same line, console log the same logic and see whats been logged. Then you can know what is being returned

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I ran this: console.log(this.msToTime(this.getMsDiff(futureDate))) and it returned 02:27:00

Comment: FYI - nothing is being returned because the line that calls the logic isn't hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `msToTime` function inside rxjs [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map)

```
return source.pipe(
  map(_ => this.msToTime(this.getMsDiff(futureDate)))
);
```

In template you see [object, object] because you are returning Observable from `filter` pipe, so use [Async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to subscribe it like

```
<div> date countdown: {{ '2021-10-06T17:27:10.740z' | filter | async }} </div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-example-4pich8?file=app%2FfilterPipe.ts)

Comment: all I needed was the async pipe. thanks for the help